# AzureAD Priviledged Access Management (Group Management) from ServiceNow - Cannot assign time-bound (temporary) group assignment

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, servicenow

Trying to use API to temporarily assign Users to Groups in Azure AD [Azure AD - Privileged Identity Management (PIM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-configure) from ServiceNow using [ServiceNow - Azure AD Spoke](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/tokyo-application-development/page/administer/integrationhub/concept/microsoft-azure-ad-spoke.html).

I can create group assignment in AzureAD as 'Permanent' but I cannot set it to temporary ('eligible').
[My groups' types in AzureAd provisioned form ServiceNow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WN7b.png)

As per PIM docs, this is what I want:

-> Assign time-bound access to resources using start and end dates

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

The Azure AD Privileged Identity Management (PIM) service ,the eligible role  can be activated when  the role is needed to work, and its permissions expire once done.

Eligible is when use can decide to end it when needed , where as Active assignment is when the start and end dates are given prior to starting.
Both of them has the permanent option to enable role assignment that never ends.

In your case .It might have the permanent check box enabled by default:

[image]

The administrator can change this if need:

[image]

Then unselect the permanent check box , to give only temporary access:

[image]

Then the temporary access is given with the selected end date and time.

[image]

Same goes to active assignments:
[image]

**Reference:** [What is Privileged Identity Management? - Azure AD - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-configure)

Comment: I want to do it through an API.